# passwordlib fatal error

Tags: php, phar

I'm using [PasswordLib](https://github.com/ircmaxell/PHP-PasswordLib/blob/master/lib/PasswordLib/PasswordLib.php). I run my project on wamp and everything is OK but when I uploaded it to my hosting I got this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PharException' with message '__HALT_COMPILER(); must be declared in a phar' in /data/web/virtuals/9784/virtual/www/subdom/roids/_libs/PasswordLib.phar:21 Stack trace: #0 /data/web/virtuals/9784/virtual/www/subdom/roids/_libs/PasswordLib.phar(21): Phar::mapPhar('PasswordLib.pha...') #1 /data/web/virtuals/9784/virtual/www/subdom/roids/index.php(7): require_once('/data/web/virtu...') #2 {main} thrown in /data/web/virtuals/9784/virtual/www/subdom/roids/_libs/PasswordLib.phar on line 21
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PharException' with message 'phar "/data/web/virtuals/9784/virtual/www/subdom/roids/_libs/PasswordLib.phar" SHA1 signature could not be verified: broken signature' in /data/web/virtuals/9784/virtual/www/subdom/roids/_libs/PasswordLib.phar:21 Stack trace: #0 /data/web/virtuals/9784/virtual/www/subdom/roids/_libs/PasswordLib.phar(21): Phar::mapPhar('PasswordLib.pha...') #1 /data/web/virtuals/9784/virtual/www/subdom/roids/index.php(7): require_once('/data/web/virtu...') #2 {main} thrown in /data/web/virtuals/9784/virtual/www/subdom/roids/_libs/PasswordLib.phar on line 21

Do you have any ideas what the problem could be ?

Thanks

Comment: *Error 1:* `All stubs must end with __HALT_COMPILER(); or the file is not a valid Phar archive.` Check the source, maybe you can add it manually. *Error 2:* What broken signature mostly means is that the created hash is not the valid length of which SHA1 requires. It might be that your host has compiled some custom PHP libs that are causing this. If you haven't yet; try to enable `E_ALL` to see absolutely all notices/warnings/errors. Maybe you can reside to your host asking this question. My host is always very helpful with these problems after uploading (locally) valid code.

Answer (score 0):

[__halt_complier()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.halt-compiler.php) needs PHP 5.1.0 or later, is your hosting using an older version?

You can call [phpinfo()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php%20phpinfo%28%29) to find out what version you are running.

Comment: version of php 5.3.21. [PHPinfo](http://46.28.105.79/info.php) of my hosting

Also I have one more error (edit post) which disappeear after relaoding to the one which I posted

Comment: @MrZebra, The issue shouldn't be due to the version. Hardly anyone uses PHP 5.1 now.....